# Trouble calling async function with @escaping handler

Tags: swift

I'm currently working with Firebase and Firestore and I'm working with their distributed counter system and have created a function with a `@escaping` handler that should return a value I can assign and then display. here's the code:

```
func getCount(ref: DocumentReference, handler: @escaping(_ querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot,_ err: Error) -> Void) {
        ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            var totalCount = 0
            if err != nil {
               print("error getting total count")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let count = document.data()["count"] as! Int
                    totalCount += count

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm having trouble calling the function and there isn't too much information that gives me a solid grasp about this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I call it here:

```
getCount(ref: Featuredlikes {
                        ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                        var totalCount = 0
                        if err != nil {
                           print("error getting total count")
                        } else {
                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                let count = document.data()["count"] as! Int
                                totalCount += count
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But evidently it isn't right I'm getting since I'm getting unrelated errors in the swiftui part of my code.

Comment: What does “I'm having trouble calling the function” mean? At the moment I don’t see you calling it at all.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code posted that you are trying to call `handler`.

Comment: I was looking for help for the code calling it the whole point of the question... I'm aware that I have just posted the code definition and my question was how can I call it.

Comment: So you don’t know how to call a function? Or you don’t understand what a completion handler is? This might help: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your code cannot work because it's impossible to *return* (strictly spoken the closure does not return anything) a non-optional snapshot and non-optional error simultaneously. Declare both parameters as optional. By the way an underscore character and parameter label in the closure declaration is Swift 2 legacy code.

You have to call `handler` either with `nil` snapshot and the `error` instance or vice versa.

```
func getCount(ref: DocumentReference, handler: @escaping(QuerySnapshot?, Error?) -> Void) {
    ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let error = err {
           handler(nil, error)
        } else {
           handler(querySnapshot, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Or with the modern `Result` API

```
func getCount(ref: DocumentReference, handler: @escaping(Result<QuerySnapshot, Error>) -> Void) {
    ref.collection("shards").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let error = err {
           handler(.failure(error))
        } else {
           handler(.success(querySnapshot))
        }
    }
}
```